# Could Python be compiled to run on the V8 Engine?

Tags: python, v8

Presumably Javascript is compiled to some kind of byte-code to run on the V8 Engine? Is Python a similar enough language that we can imagine Python being compiled to the same byte-code and run on the V8?

Any projects trying to do this?

Comment: Is this a question about optimizing python, or is this a question about compiling Python to a form that can be directly executed by the Javascript interpreter on current browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 doesn't actually have a general purpose bytecode.  There's a regexp byte code, but support is not usually compiled in.  There's a deserialization byte code and a relocation information byte code, but both are implemtation details and you can't use them for anything.

So what you are looking for is something that compiles to JS source code.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there are no projects that specifically target the V8 virtual machine. However, [Pypy](http://pypy.org/) and the erstwhile Unladen Swallow (now merged into the py3k-jit branch of the main CPython tree), both attempt to just-in-time compile Python into native code, similar to what V8 does with Javascript.

As @something says, [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) allows you to write Python code and translate it into Javascript, much like GWT does with Java. Any code translated thus would have the same benefits to running under V8 as any other Javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

There are already three projects that provide a Python to Javascript compiler. The resulting Javascript can then be run on any engine including V8. Look for Pyjamas, Skulpt and Py2JS.

This is not the same as compiling Python to V8 bytecodes, but the end result is much the same.

Answer (score 0):

For ways to run python inside browsers, see the python wiki page [WebBrowserProgramming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming).

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for something like "Pyjamas"?
http://pyjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://repl.it/ - it's an example of a pretty much complete Python interpreter compiled to JavaScript. This was achieved thanks to [Emscripten](http://emscripten.org) - a compiler of LLVM bytecode to Javascript.

Answer (score -5):

Python is already compiled to bytecode and executed.  This is what the .pyc files are in CPython. Jython likewise compiles to Java bytecode (dynamically), and so does IronPython for .NET

Comment: This has nothing to do with the V8 Javascript engine.

Comment: The question is about targeting V8, specifically, not about Python byte codes in general.

Comment: Way I interpreted the question, it was about compiling python to bytecode, of which V8 was given as an example.